How to configure SOLR to detect encoding on fields of type 'string'
We have a system that has Solr 8.2 as suggested, but we would like to use a more recent version.
On the 8.2 version all fields are correctly encoded, but on 8.11 or 9.7 fields of type string breaks the encoding.
An example: the word "elaboração" gets indexed to "elabora??o"
Fields of type text_general doesn't suffer on this encoding problem.
Any suggestion to fix this?

Edit
I was wrong. There is nothing to do with field types. Whats is relevant is how the fields are provided to Solr: request body or request query parameters.

There really isn't any encoding to detect - Solr expects everything as UTF-8. Are you sure you haven't changed something else in the process?

Thanks @MatsLindh, I'm sure that nothing changed despite Solr version. I hacked the application to force UTF-8 encoding on requests params an I can confirm this works, but the question now is why 8.2 works without explicit enconding?

Also, what I undertand is that Solr doesn't expects "everything" as UTF-8, body entities can inform the encoding, this is why some fields of type text_general works.
